# Is my answer correct, or textbook correct?

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

My answer is 9.45,

textbook is 4.7

I did cos 38 = x / 12,

12 cos 38 = x

9.45 = x

ty in advance

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I deleted my answer now after you fixed that little mistake.  Yes, I agree with your answer, too!

Comment: You rounded wrong - it's $9.46$ to the nearest 100th place.